# Layer error: Classifier training failed: 'Only one class.'

Tags: google-earth-engine

I keep getting this error:

> Layer error: Classifier training failed: 'Only one class.'

despite I ensure that the landcover has its own value for Processing 2015 Reg3. Here is my code  https://code.earthengine.google.com/da07b55a5dfd1c43ab8433b43c0fd00a

```
// Processing 2015 Reg3

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                    // 1) Set up the map                 //
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

//Center the map to the region of interest using the region shapefile
Map.centerObject(Reg3,7)
Map.setOptions('satellite')


///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//         ) Set up Filtered Landsat Composite 7 2007        //
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

//2.1) Cloud Masking
////////////////////

//Landsat data includes a 'pixel_qa' band which can be used to create 
//     a function to mask clouds

function maskClouds(image) {

  // Bits 3 and 5 are cloud shadow and cloud, respectively.
    var cloudShadowBitMask = ee.Number(2).pow(3).int();
    var cloudsBitMask = ee.Number(2).pow(5).int();  

    // Get the pixel QA band.
    var qa = image.select('pixel_qa');

    // Both flags should be set to zero, indicating clear conditions.
    var mask = qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudShadowBitMask).eq(0).and(qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudsBitMask).eq(0)); 

  // Return the masked image, scaled to [0, 1].
  return image.updateMask(mask).divide(10000).copyProperties(image, ["system:time_start"]);
}

//2.2) Adding Spectral Indices
///////////////////////////////

// This function maps spectral indices for Mangrove Mapping using Landsat 8 Imagery
var addIndicesL8 = function(img) {
  // NDVI
  var ndvi = img.normalizedDifference(['B5','B4']).rename('NDVI');
  // NDMI (Normalized Difference Mangrove Index - Shi et al 2016 - New spectral metrics for mangrove forest identification)
  var ndmi = img.normalizedDifference(['B7','B3']).rename('NDMI');
  // MNDWI (Modified Normalized Difference Water Index - Hanqiu Xu, 2006)
  var mndwi = img.normalizedDifference(['B3','B6']).rename('MNDWI');
  // SR (Simple Ratio)
  var sr = img.select('B5').divide(img.select('B4')).rename('SR');
  // Band Ratio 54
  var ratio54 = img.select('B6').divide(img.select('B5')).rename('R54');
  // Band Ratio 35
  var ratio35 = img.select('B4').divide(img.select('B6')).rename('R35');
  // GCVI
  var gcvi = img.expression('(NIR/GREEN)-1',{
    'NIR':img.select('B5'),
    'GREEN':img.select('B3')
  }).rename('GCVI');
  return img
    .addBands(ndvi)
    .addBands(ndmi)
    .addBands(mndwi)
    .addBands(sr)
    .addBands(ratio54)
    .addBands(ratio35)
    .addBands(gcvi);
};

//2.3) Filter Landsat data by Date and Region
/////////////////////////////////////////////

// Temporal Parameters

// Select the desired central year here
var year3 = 2015; 

// Start date will be set one year before the central year
var startDate3 = (year3)+'-01-01'; 

// End date will be set to one year later than the central year.
var endDate3 = (year3)+'-12-31'; 

//2.4) Apply filters and masks to Landsat 8 imagery
///////////////////////////////////////////////////

var l8= ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_SR')
      .filterDate(startDate3, endDate3)
    .map(maskClouds) // Masks for clouds and cloud-shadows
    .map(addIndicesL8); // Add the indices
//2.5) Composite the Landsat image collection
/////////////////////////////////////////////
//You can composite on a per pixel, per-band basis using .median()
// OR with quality bands like .qualityMosaic('NDVI')

var composite3 = l8
              // Uses the median reducer
              .median() 
              // Clips the composite to our area of interest
              .clip(Reg3); 

//2.6) Mask to areas of low elevation and high NDVI and MNDWI
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

// Clip SRTM data to region
var srtmClip3 = SRTM.clip(Reg3);

//Mask to elevations less than 65 meters
var elevationMask3 = srtmClip3.lt(65);

//Used the NDVI and MNDWI bands to create masks
var NDVIMask3 = composite3.select('NDVI').gt(0.25);
var MNDWIMask3 = composite3.select('MNDWI').gt(-0.50);

//Apply the masks
var compositeNew3 = composite3
                        .updateMask(NDVIMask3)
                        .updateMask(MNDWIMask3)
                        .updateMask(elevationMask3)

// //2.7) Display results
// ///////////////////////

// //Select bands and parameters for visualization
var visPar3 = {bands:['B6','B10','B5'], min: 0, max: 0.35}; 

//Add layer to map
// Map.addLayer(compositeNew3.clip(Reg3), visPar3, 'Landsat Composite 2015')


// ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// //          3) Construct Random Forest Model                 //
// ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

// //3.1) Prepare training data and predictors
// ////////////////////////////////////////////

//After drawing training polygons, merge them together
var classes3 = Mangrove3.merge(NonMangrove3)

//Define the bands you want to include in the model
var bands3 = ['B6','B10','B5','NDVI','MNDWI','SR','GCVI']

//Create a variable called image to select the bands of interest and clip to geometry
var image3 = compositeNew3.select(bands3).clip(Reg3)

//Assemble samples for the model
var samples3 = image3.sampleRegions({
    collection: classes3, // Set of geometries selected for training
    properties: ['landcover3'], // Label from each geometry
    scale: 30 // Make each sample the same size as Landsat pixel
    }).randomColumn('random'); // creates a column with random numbers

//Here we randomly split our samples to set some aside for testing our model's accuracy
// using the "random" column we created
var split3 = 0.8; // Roughly 80% for training, 20% for testing.
var training3 = samples3.filter(ee.Filter.lt('random', split3)); //Subset training data
var testing3 = samples3.filter(ee.Filter.gte('random', split3)); //Subset testing data


// Print these variables to see how much training and testing data you are using
    print('Samples3 n =', samples3.aggregate_count('.all'));
    print('Training3 n =', training3.aggregate_count('.all'));
    print('Testing3 n =', testing3.aggregate_count('.all'));

//3.2) Begin Random Forest Classification
/////////////////////////////////////////

//.smileRandomForest is used to run the model. Here we run the model using 100 trees
// and 5 randomly selected predictors per split ("(100,5)")
    var classifier3 = ee.Classifier.smileRandomForest(100,5).train({ 
    features: training3.select(['B6','B10','B5','NDVI','MNDWI','SR','GCVI', 'landcover3']), //Train using bands and landcover property
    classProperty: 'landcover3', //Pull the landcover property from classes
    inputProperties: bands3
    });

// //View explain to see how each band contributes to the classifier
print(classifier3.explain(),'Explain')

//3.3) Test the accuracy of the model
//////////////////////////////////////

    var validation3 = testing3.classify(classifier3);
    var testAccuracy3 = validation3.errorMatrix('landcover3', 'classification');
    print('Validation error matrix RF: ', testAccuracy3);
    print('Validation overall accuracy RF: ', testAccuracy3.accuracy());

//3.4) Classify the Landsat composite using the Random Forest model
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    var classifiedrf3 = image3.select(bands3) // select the predictors
                      .classify(classifier3); // .classify applies the Random Forest

//The model results may be "noisy". To reduce noise, create a mask to mask
// unconnected pixels
    var pixelcount3 = classifiedrf3.connectedPixelCount(100, false); //Create an image that shows the number of pixels each pixel is connected to
    var countmask3 = pixelcount3.select(0).gt(25); //filter out all pixels connected to 4 or less 

//Mask the results to only display mangrove extent
    var classMask3 = classifiedrf3.select('classification').gt(0)
    var classed3 = classifiedrf3.updateMask(countmask3).updateMask(classMask3)

// //3.5) Map results
// ////////////////////

// //Add classification to map
// Map.addLayer (classed3, {min: 1, max: 1, palette:'blue'}, 'New Mangrove Extent 2015 Reg3');


// ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// //          4) SAR Random Forest Classification              //
// ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

// //4.1) Create Bounds Using Landsat Results
// /////////////////////////////////////////////

//Vectorize results of Landsat classification
var Reg3Vec = classed3.reduceToVectors({
  geometry:Reg3,
  scale:30,
  geometryType: 'polygon',
  maxPixels:1e13,
  labelProperty: 'class',
})

// View vectorized mangrove extent
// Map.addLayer(Reg3Vec,{},'Mangrove Extent Vector 2015 Reg3')

// Export Results to Asset for Faster Code
// Export.table.toAsset({
//   collection: Reg3Vec,
//   description:'VectorizedGuyana2015Reg3'

// });

//4.2) Filter Sentinel data to date and region of interest
/////////////////////////////////////////////

var sentinel3 = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S1_GRD')
              .filterDate(startDate3, endDate3)

//4.3) Get Sentinel's dual polarization
////////////////////////////////////////////

// Filter by metadata properties.
var vh = sentinel3
  // Filter to get images with VV and VH dual polarization.
  .filter(ee.Filter.listContains('transmitterReceiverPolarisation', 'VV'))
  .filter(ee.Filter.listContains('transmitterReceiverPolarisation', 'VH'))
  // Filter to get images collected in interferometric wide swath mode.
  .filter(ee.Filter.eq('instrumentMode', 'IW'));

// Filter to get images from different look angles.
var vhAscending3 = vh.filter(ee.Filter.eq('orbitProperties_pass', 'ASCENDING'));
var vhDescending3 = vh.filter(ee.Filter.eq('orbitProperties_pass', 'DESCENDING'));


//4.3) Create a composite from means at different polarizations and look angles.
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

var S1composite3 = ee.Image.cat([
  vhAscending3.select('VH').mean(),
  ee.ImageCollection(vhAscending3.select('VV').merge(vhDescending3.select('VV'))).mean(),
  vhDescending3.select('VH').mean()
]).focal_median();


//4.3) Display results
///////////////////////

// Display as a composite of polarization and backscattering characteristics.
Map.centerObject(Reg3, 11);
// Map.addLayer(S1composite3.clip(Reg2), {min: [-15, -20, -25], max: [-10, 10, -5]}, 'Sentinel Composite 2015 Reg3');


// ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// //          5) Construct  New Random Forest Model           //
// ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

// //5.1) Prepare training data and predictors
// ////////////////////////////////////////////
// ee.FeatureCollection('projects/mangrovescience/VectorizedGuyana2019')

// //Define the bands you want to include in the model
var S1bands3 = ['VV','VH']//Red Edge Bands

//Subset Sentinel Composite to Landsat Results
var compositeMask3 = S1composite3.clip(Reg3Vec)

// //Assemble samples for the model
var S1samples3 = compositeMask3.select(S1bands3).sampleRegions({
collection: classes3, // Set of geometries selected in 4.1
properties: ['landcover3'], // Label from each geometry
scale: 30 // Make each sample the same size as Landsat pixel
}).randomColumn('random'); // creates a column with random numbers


// //5.2) Begin Random Forest Classification
// /////////////////////////////////////////

var S1classifier3 = ee.Classifier.smileRandomForest(100,2).train({ //We use 2 variables instead of 5
features: S1samples3.select(['VV','VH', 'landcover3']),
classProperty: 'landcover3',
inputProperties: S1bands3
});


// //5.3) Classify the Sentinel composite using the Random Forest model
// ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

var S1classified3 = compositeMask3.select(S1bands3) // select the predictors
.classify(S1classifier3); // apply the Random Forest

//The model results may be "noisy". To reduce noise, create a mask to mask
// unconnected pixels
    var S1pixelcount3 = S1classified3.connectedPixelCount(100, false); //Create an image that shows the number of pixels each pixel is connected to
    var S1countmask3 = S1pixelcount3.select(0).gt(25); //filter out all pixels connected to 4 or less 

//Mask the results to only display mangrove extent
    var S1classMask3 = S1classified3.select('classification').gt(0)
    var S1classed3 =  S1classified3.updateMask(S1countmask3).updateMask(S1classMask3)

//5.5) Map results
//////////////////

//Add classification to map
Map.addLayer (S1classed3, {min: 1, max: 1, palette:'green'}, 'Mangrove Extent 2015 SAR Reg3');

Export.image.toDrive({
  image: S1classed2,
  description: '2015 Reg2 Mangrove Extent',
  region: Reg2,
  scale: 30,
  maxPixels: 1e13
  });


// // ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// // //          6) Calculate Results                              //
// // ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

// //6.1) Calculate Mangrove Area 
// ///////////////////////////////////////

//Use reduceRegion with a Sum reducer to calculate total area
var Reg2Area = S1classed2.multiply(ee.Image.pixelArea()).divide(10000).reduceRegion({
      reducer:ee.Reducer.sum(),
      geometry:Reg2,
      scale: 30,
      maxPixels:1e13,
      tileScale: 16
      }).get('classification');

print(Reg2Area, 'Reg 2 Mangrove Extent in ha')
```

Comment: Please add your code to the question body, not only link.

Comment: There is a huge amount of code here that is not at all relevant to the problem. Please make a minimum working example, it will be mch easier for people to read, and in doing so you might find the issue yourself.